# Javascript: Creating objects with multiple loops

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop

I have a question about mock-data with multiple reviews for each product.

`review_id` is incremented in order of pk, and`product_id` is going to have duplicate values ​​because there may be multiple reviews on the same product. As shown below:

```js
const data = [
  { review_id: 1, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 2, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 3, product_id: 2 },
  { review_id: 4, product_id: 2 },
  { review_id: 5, product_id: 3 },
  { review_id: 6, product_id: 3 },

 (...)

];
```

I tried to create an object in an array using a double loop:

```js
const reviewLength = 10;
const productLength = 2;

const mappedReview = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= reviewLength; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= productLength; j++) {
    const review_id = i * j;
    const product_id = j;

    mappedReview[i * j - 1] = {
      review_id,
      product_id
    };
  }
}

console.log(mappedReview);
```

But instead of object, it was printed on the console as follows:

```sh
[ { review_id: 1, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 2, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 3, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 4, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 5, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 6, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 7, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 8, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 9, product_id: 1 },
  { review_id: 10, product_id: 1 },
  <1 empty item>,
  { review_id: 12, product_id: 2 },
  <1 empty item>,
  { review_id: 14, product_id: 2 },
  <1 empty item>,
  { review_id: 16, product_id: 2 },
  <1 empty item>,
  { review_id: 18, product_id: 2 },
  <1 empty item>,
  { review_id: 20, product_id: 2 } ]
```

It seems like you have executed the loop correctly, `<1 empty item>` (as a result of what you have written in the file, it appears as `null`).

Comment: Why not just `.push` to the array? Also note your method leads to duplicate review IDs.

Comment: would it not be better to have a seaprate object for each product and within that object would be an array of reviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `review_id` always increases, I'd just use a single loop and increment `product_id` each time we've output `productLength` entries:

```js
const reviewLength = 10;
const productLength = 2;

const mappedReview = [];
let product_id = 1;
let product_counter = 1; // Used to tell when to increment product_id
for (let review_id = 1; review_id <= reviewLength; review_id++) {
    // Add this object
    mappedReview.push({review_id, product_id});
    // Increment product_id if appropriate
    if (product_counter++ === productLength) {
        ++product_id;
        product_counter = 1;
    }
}

console.log(mappedReview);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or using a calculation for `product_id` rather than the counter:

```js
const reviewLength = 10;
const productLength = 2;

const mappedReview = [];
for (let review_id = 1; review_id <= reviewLength; review_id++) {
    // Add this object
    mappedReview.push({
        review_id,
        product_id: Math.ceil(review_id / productLength)
     });
}

console.log(mappedReview);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

In a comment you asked:

> Can I use the array methods map,`reduce`, etc. to express this case?

You could shoehorn it into a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call (by creating an array, [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)ing it, and then using `map`), but using the mapping callback feature of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) would make more sense:

```js
const reviewLength = 10;
const productLength = 2;

const mappedReview = Array.from({length: reviewLength}, (_, index) => ({
    review_id: index + 1,
    product_id: Math.ceil((index + 1) / productLength)
}));

console.log(mappedReview);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

To shoehorn a `map` in there, you'd `Array.from({length: reviewLength},` with (`Array(reviewLength).fill().map(`:

```
const mappedReview = Array(reviewLength).fill(0).map((_, index) => ({
    // ...
}));
```

Comment: I have a question. Can I use the array methods `map`,` reduce`, etc. to express this case?

Comment: @YangwookJeong - `map` and `reduce` wouldn't make sense here. The closest I can see to something along those lines would be to use `Array.from`'s mapping callback and either close over `product_id` and `product_counter` or use a calculation to figure out the `product_id` from the index. I've updated the answer to show how to do that.